# Concat the value of object key with the value of all the previous objects with the same key inside of a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state

I have a state array of object and i want to concat each URL of an object with all the URLs of the previous objects of it:

```
    navigation:[    
     {
        "type": "LINK",
        "uri": "arbress"
    },
    
    {
        "type": "LINK",
        "uri": "arbres-a-grand-developpement"
    },

    {
        "type": "LINK",
        "uri": "Acer-xfreemanii"
    }
  ]
```

An i want the result to be like this :

```
navigation:[    
         {
            "type": "LINK",
            "uri": "arbress"
        },
        
        {
            "type": "LINK",
            "uri": "arbress/arbres-a-grand-developpement"
        },

        {             
            "type": "LINK",
            "uri": "arbress/arbres-a-grand-developpement/Acer-xfreemanii"
        }
      ]
```

this is my code but it changed nothing, i always get the initial state:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const newState = navigation.map((obj1) => {
            if(obj1.type === 'LINK'){
                navigation.map((obj2) => {
                    if (obj2 === 'LINK'){
                        return {...obj1, uri: obj2.uri+"/"+uri}
                    }
                })
            }
            return obj1;
        })

        setNavigation(newState)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index being iterated over in the `.map` callback so you can slice the `navigation` array from 0 to the index, then join the `uri`s of each prior object.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNavigation(
    navigation
      .filter(obj => obj.type === 'LINK')
      .map((_, i, arr) => ({
        type: 'LINK',
        uri: arr
          .slice(0, i + 1) // include this item being iterated over in the result
          .map(obj => obj.uri)
          .join('/'),
      }))
  );
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to repeated slices would be to pass a string in a closure (here using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) passed to the `map()` call) and simply concatenate the next uri part with it on each iteration of the `map()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNavigation((navigation) => (
    navigation
      .filter(({type}) => type === 'LINK')
      .map(
        ((uri) => ({type, uri: tail}) => {
          uri = uri === '' ? tail : `${uri}/${tail}`;
          return {type, uri};
        })('')
      )
  ));
}, []);
```